# If I use alignas on a class, is the first member or base class aligned?

Tags: c++, alignment

If I declare my class `struct alignas(16) C { int x; };`, is `x` guaranteed to be aligned to 16 bytes or could the compiler pad it on the “left”? What about `template <typename T, std::size_t Align> struct alignas(Align) Aligned : T { using T::T; };`? Would the `T` of `Aligned<T, N>` be aligned to `N`? Is that the right way to make a type that is a `T` that is always aligned?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If I declare my class `struct alignas(16) C { int x; };`, is `x` guaranteed to be aligned to 16 bytes or could the compiler pad it on the “left”?

In this case, `x` has to be on the 16 byte boundary because you have a [standard layout class](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Standard_layout).  A standard layout class comes with a guarantee that the first member of the class shares the same address as the class itself, meaning it will have the same alignment.

> What about `template <typename T, std::size_t Align> struct alignas(Align) Aligned : T { using T::T; };`?

This is the same case as long as `T` is a standard layout class.  If it is then `Aligned` has standard layout, and the first base class subobject is guaranteed to be at the start of the object in memory, so it has the same alignment.

> Is that the right way to make a type that is a `T` that is always aligned?

It's an way.  Another approach would be to use a `std::aligned_storage` object and then use placement new to emplace an object into that aligned storage.

Comment: After seeing your answer, I realized I hadn't considered `template <typename T, std::size_t Algn> using Aligned = alignas(Algn) T;`. But no, that's not a thing for some reason: https://godbolt.org/z/jK8KbaT8E